# Function that returns different types?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a container class that contains two properties:

- string contents
- bool isCommaSeperated

And a function:

```
? compute()
{
    if(this.isCommaSeperated)
    {
        return contents.split(",").toList();
    }
    else
    {
        return contents;
    }
}
```

Is there a way for this function to return either a string or a list of strings?
Or what type of design would allow me to achieve something similar?

Comment: Think about how you would _use_ the function.  What do you do with the result? Do you plan to perform a type check every time you call the function?

Answer (score 7):

I would just return both results as a collection:

```
IList<string> compute()
{
    if (this.isCommaSeperated)
    {
        return contents.Split(",");  // No need to turn the array into a list
    }

    return new[] { contents };   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` to implement that:

```
dynamic Compute(bool isCommaSeperated)
{
    if(isCommaSeperated)
    {
        return contents.Split(",").ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return contents;
    }
}
```

Code will still preserve type information, but let you return any type you like and fail at run-time if you try to use methods of another type.

Note that you give up compile type safety by doing it. Depending on your needs it may be ok, but consider is some alternative solution that preserve compile type safety would work better. I.e. returning single element array as shown in istme86's [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43926921/477420).

Answer (score 0):

While `IEnumerable<string>` is the standard solution, you could also try the new [StringValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues) struct which implicitly casts between string values and string arrays:

```cs
StringValues a = "A";
StringValues b = new string[] { "A", "B" };
StringValues c = null;

Console.WriteLine(a.Contains("A"));
// true

Console.WriteLine(b.Any(x => x == a));
// true

Console.WriteLine(c.Any());
// false
```